# Strip the path to the pdb

Tags: visual-studio

Per default, when compiling a Visual Studio project in release mode, the complete path to the pdb is put into the image file, e.g.:

```
c:\myprojects\demo\release\test.pdb
```

Using an undocumented linker switch (`/pdbpath:none`) one can force Visual Studio 2008 to reduce the full qualified name of the pdb, e.g:

```
test.pdb
```

I need to do the same with a project which is still built using **VC6**.

I tried the "`/pdbpath:none`" switch at the project settings level, but the linker complains about this unknown switch.

Does anyone knows a method (or a tool) to accomplish this either when linking a VC6 project or afterwards directly at the image level?

Comment: This switch is available (documented) starting with Visual Studio 2010

Comment: This switch is also working with Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: There is a tool called peupdate ([website here](http://bytepointer.com/tools/index.htm#peupdate)) that will remove, strip or otherwise change this PDB string to any arbitrary value for an EXE or DLL.  For your particular question, you would use the "-s" (strip) option to remove the path but leave the filename intact.

Comment: See answers in [Remove PDB references from released file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109189/remove-pdb-references-from-released-file/39000873)

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to use [pdbstr.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from MS directly.  It allows for direct extraction, update, and misc other functions directly, independent of compiler version (up to the last supported version, which I think is VS2013 right now).  We use it to add SVN linkings directly to PDBs which we then store in local symbol stores using srctool.

Comment: Thanks! Interesting to see that this utility uses Alternate Data Stream (ADS)..."to insert the version control information into the "srcsrv" alternative stream of the target .pdb file".

Comment: What would an example command line be to use pdbstr.exe? Even with the docs, I couldn't figure it out how to strip the path.

Comment: @byteptr Sorry for the late reply.  We use a Poweshell Script to build our new block in a temporary stream file ($streamContent), and then call the executable directly like this:

. "$ToolPath"/pdbstr.exe -w -s:srcsrv "-p:$pdbFullName" "-i:$streamContent"

This adds the given stream as a srcsrv stream to the pdb specified in $pdbFullName, which includes the path and all that.

Answer (score 3):

For newer `link.exe` versions, the syntax changed.

The option you want is now `/pdbaltpath:%_PDB%`

It is documented on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd998269.aspx

> **`%_PDB%`** expands to the file name of the actual .pdb file without any path information

For VC6, you might want to continue using the same compilers but a new version of `link.exe`.

The Windows Driver Kits also come with a tool named `binplace.exe` which can modify this information post-build.

Comment: This seems to be broken for static libraries. LNK4044: unrecognized option '/pdbaltpath:%_PDB%'; ignored

Comment: @syplex: What version of the linker are you using?  And what do static libraries have to do with your problem?

Comment: Tried a few versions. Up to version 14.12.25835.0. Trying to figure out how to specify or alter the PDB path for a static library. The path is embedded into .lib like it is for DLLs/EXEs (albeit differently) but there is no way to modify it. I would expect something like PDBALTPATH to work for this, but haven't found anything.

Comment: Can the /PDBALTPATH be a relative path? e.g. `..\PDBs\mydll.pdb` ?