# ASP.Net Exception Shows File Path

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, exception

When my ASP.Net MVC application encounters an error, the full file path of the c# class is displayed in the exception even though I've only deployed binaries.  E.g.

at: C:\DevelopmentServer\MVC_Project\AccountManagement.cs line 45

Where is this path information being stored?  Is it in the compiled dll and is there a way to remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is stored in the PDB files generated during the compile, and it reflects the paths to the code on the build machine.

Comment: Is there a way to stop it from storing it there?

Comment: Found it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109189/remove-pdb-references-from-released-file