# Prevent Visual Studio from using cached .pdbs

Tags: visual-studio, pdb-files

I did the following experiment: I created a statically linked C++ library solution MyLibrary (I took the code from the MSDN example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235627.aspx.) and built it. Then I created another C++ solution MyConsoleApp, using the console application template in Visual Studio (2017). I copied the MyLibrary.lib file to the root of MyConsoleApp project and added MyLibrary.lib to Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies (also had to copy over the headers too of course). What I didn't do was to copy over the MyLibrary.pdb file.

I would've expected to get a linker warning about the missing .pdb file but this was not the case. Then I moved only MyConsoleApp to another machine and tried to build it again, this time getting a missing .pdb linker warning. It seems that Visual Studio is storing the .pdb files when building a solution somewhere on the machine and is able to use those .pdb files when linking other solutions on the same machine.

I would like to be able to disable this behaviour or to be able to remove the cached .pdbs so that I could be sure that when sharing work with other developers they won't get warnings that I'm not getting on my own machine.

Comment: The DLL stores the path to the pdb file.  Something you can with Dumpbin.exe /headers, the .rdata section stores this info and Debug Directories shows what is inside of it.  Feature, not a bug.  Foisting a library without debug info on other devs is not exactly very reasonable, unless you really want to stop them from fixing your bugs.

Comment: `dumpbin /pdbpath:verbose StaticLib1.dll` indeed shows the path to the .pdb if I build the project as a dynamic library, but doesn't show anything for a static library. How to find the .pdb path for a static library?

Comment: It is the linker's job to find it.  When you link the static library in an EXE or DLL project.

Comment: How does it find it from the intermediate output directory of the library project in the scenario described in the question? Is the path stored in the .lib file in a similar way as with a .dll?

Edit: sorry, I didn't mention in the question that I found out that the .pdb in the intermediate output directory was used, I mentioned that in my own answer.

Comment: The project database stores debug info, /Fd compile option.  This doesn't have anything to do with your question.

Comment: Let me rephrase: the consumer (`MyConsoleApp`) is able to locate the `.pdb` for the static library it's depending on from the intermediate output directory of the static library (`MyLibrary`) for linking (I know that's where it's coming from, because deleting it from there causes a warning about not being able to find `MyLibrary.pdb`). This happens despite only being provided with the `MyLibrary.lib` file. Is the location of the `MyLibrary.pdb` in the intermediate output directory stored in `MyLibrary.lib` the same as with a .dll?

Comment: And can you use something like `dumpbin /pdbpath:verbose MyLibrary.lib` to see the path from the `.lib`? This command works for a `.dll` but not for a statically built `.lib`.

Comment: This is indeed a bit beside the original question since I was able to get the result I wanted already but I'm curious to know why it worked like that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171567/discussion-between-hemaolle-and-hans-passant).

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio doesn't cache the .pdb file. What happens here is that the absolute path to the original .pdb file is stored in the build outputs (.exe, .dll or .obj files) and Visual Studio is able to took it up based on that.

Check this answer for a way to prevent that: [Remove PDB references from released file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109189/remove-pdb-references-from-released-file).