# Build path in executables or DLL (Visual Studio C++/Windows)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild, relative-path

Every executable or DLL built with visual compiler has absolute path marked in it.
Regardless if it's debug or release build.

I would like to have relative path or even better to set my own prefix.
Lets say I want to obfuscate the path, so that no one will know that it was built in path C:/my_workspace/my_repository_path/...

I haven't found any option in Visual nor in MSBuild to enforce such behavior.
Is it possible to do ?

Comment: ? I have never such thing.....Are you sure you have disabled debug information?

Comment: the path to the PDB file? If so https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596628/strip-the-path-to-the-pdb

Comment: Actually those are paths to cpp files. Shouldn't such information be hidden in pdb file ?
Anyways, even for PDB it would good to have relative path.